# How to find the MAX of a calculated value in a window?

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple database table with three columns: `id`, `x`, `y`. `x` and `y` are just the coordinates of points in a line. I want to using the SQLite Window function to partition the table using a sliding window of three rows, and then get the `y` value that is the furthest from the `y` value of the first coordinate (row) in the window.

An example:

```
| id | x | y |
|----|---|---|
|  1 | 1 | .5|
|  2 | 2 | .9|
|  3 | 3 | .7| 
|  4 | 4 |1.1|
|  5 | 5 | 1 |
```

So the first partition would consist of:

```
| id | x | y |
|----|---|---|
|  1 | 1 | .5|
|  2 | 2 | .9|
|  3 | 3 | .7|
```

And the desired result would be:

```
| id | x | y | d |
|----|---|---|---|
|  1 | 1 | .5| .4|
|  2 | 2 | .9|
|  3 | 3 | .7|
```

Since the the window with `id` = 1 as the `CURRENT ROW` would have a maximum variation of .4; the maximum distance between the `y` value of the first row in the partition, `.5`, and `.9`, is `.4`.

The final expected result:

```
| id | x | y | d |
|----|---|---|---|
|  1 | 1 | .5| .4|
|  2 | 2 | .9| .2|
|  3 | 3 | .7| .4|
|  4 | 4 |1.1| .1|
|  5 | 5 | 1 |   |
```

I've tried using a window function like: `WINDOW win1 AS (ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING` which gives me the correct window.

With the window defined, I tried doing something like:

```
SELECT
    max(abs(y - first_value(y) OVER win1)) AS d
FROM t
WINDOW win1 AS (ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
```

But I get an error for misuse of `first_value`.

I think the problem I have is this is not the proper approach to calculate over each row of a partition, but I could not find another solution or approach that matches what I am trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row of your table you define a window starting from the current row up to the next 2 rows.
In your code `y` is the value in the current row and `first_value()` is the 1st value of `y` of the current window which is also the value of `y` of the current row.
So even if your code was syntactically correct the difference you calculate would always return `0`.
  
It's easier to solve your problem with [`LEAD()`](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    LEAD(y, 1) OVER () AS y1,
    LEAD(y, 2) OVER () AS y2
  FROM tablename
)  
SELECT 
  id, x, y, 
  MAX(ABS(y - y1), COALESCE(ABS(y - y2), 0)) d 
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3Fq1jjz4PMKhmR15hpX5q7/0).
Results:

```
id  x   y   d
1   1   0.5 0.4
2   2   0.9 0.2
3   3   0.7 0.4
4   4   1.1 0.1
5   5   1.0
```